# Rest Assured - send a pojo in an array

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a Pojo that creates a json object with values
This creates an object fine e.g.

```
public class Collections {

private String reference;
private String collectionDate;

public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

public String getCollectionDate() {
    return collectionDate;
}

public void setCollectionDate(String collectionDate) {
    this.collectionDate = collectionDate;
}}
```

This creates a json object just fine

`{reference:"test",collectionDate:"test"}`

But my api only accepts objects encapsulated as an array e.g.

`[{reference:"test",collectionDate:"test"}]`

I then want to pass this object in an array into the Body of me restAssured POST request

can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple options...

```
List<Collection> collections = new ArrayList<>();
collections.add(new Collection("foo", "bar"));
```

or...

```
List<Collection> collections = List.of(new Collection("foo", "bar"));
```

Note, i've assumed your pojo would be called 'Collection' rather than 'Collections'

Whatever you're using to convert it into Json should also parse the above into the form you're expecting.